# How to allow cookie in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, cookies

I have a working react frontend on localhost during testing, but when I deploy to AWS, the cookie is not working at all. I can see that cookies are not set when inspecting the web page. I am using cookie Session and here is the setting.

```
app.use(cookieSession({
name: 'session',
secret: 'blablba',
// Cookie Options
sameSite: 'none',
secure : true,
maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
httpOnly: true,
signed: false
}))
```

The cors setting

```
app.use(cors({
origin: 'example.com',
//origin: true,
credentials: true
}));
```

It is strange, and I assume my app can work when deploy to ec2 instead of s3. But I have to deploy to S3 because I am trying to do ci/cd here.

Thanks!